# Ajax auto refresh - Not effecting scrolling

Tags: ajax

I am using ajax to auto refresh a div tag using this code in my index.php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
setInterval(function() {
$('#messanges').load('messanges.php');
}, 1000); 
});
</script>

<div id="messanges"></div>
<textarea name="chat_input" id="chat_input"></textarea>
```

In messanges.php I have a auto scroll down code. 
Cause I want it to start at the bottom when entering the chat.

```
<head>
<script>
var chat_height = $('#chat').outerHeight();
$('#chat_box').scrollTop(chat_height);
</script>
</head>

<div id="chat_box" style="height:700px; overflow:auto">
<div id="chat">
<div id="Name">Test user:</div>
<div id="img"><img src="picture.png" /></img></div>
<p class="triangle-isosceles left">
"Test" </p> 
</div>
```

The code is now forcing the scroll to stay at the bottom because of the ajax auto refresh.
How can I make it auto refresh, but if I want to scroll up it will not force me down when it refresh?

Comment: does the message.php also gets the chat content ? if yes... try to get the current scroll position... if its at the bottom, do autoscroll else dont untill user scrolls back down or refreshes page. or simply add a chekcbox "autoscroll" on/off :)

Answer (score 0):

try some like this

```
<head>
<script>
    var chat_height = $('#chat').outerHeight();
    if($('.doScroll').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#chat_box').scrollTop(chat_height);
    }
</script>
</head>

<input type="checkbox" class="doScroll" checked />
<div id="chat_box" style="height:700px; overflow:auto">
<div id="chat">
    <div id="Name">Test user:</div>
    <div id="img"><img src="picture.png" /></img></div>
    <p class="triangle-isosceles left">"Test" </p> 
</div>
```